# Aligning a TextView and ImageView inside a LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have a ListView with custom adapter and a layout for items in this List. The layout for the items is just a TextView with an ImageView. The image should be aligned to the right side of the screen. However, the image's position is shifting a bit, depending on the length of the text in the TextView. This is what it looks like:

[image: screenshot]

This is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtCategoryName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/list_text_color"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgArrowRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_44"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_description_right_arrow"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

How can I make the image be always aligned to the right, without being nudged?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) should solve your problem nicely using `android:layout_alignParentRight` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft`.  Something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtCategoryName"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/list_text_color"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgArrowRight"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_44"
    android:contentDescription="@string/img_description_right_arrow"/>
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but you have to make sure that text inside `TextView` will never going to be larger than screen size , otherwise it will appear above `ImageView` content. Maybe `android:layout_toLeftOf="+@+id/imgArrowRight"` will do the trick.

Comment: how to do this programatically?

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and using align parent right on the image and align parent left on the TextView.