# Different behaviour from button images

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

Following my previous question, [Fitting three buttons and a background image in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27242624/fitting-three-buttons-and-a-background-image-in-android), I have now what I wanted, but there is now a minor issue that I don't understand.
There are three buttons,each button with an image, the three images have the same size, but they are shown differently. Image 2 starts at the left border, but images 1 and 3 have a margin at the left side.

[image]

From the XML file, I don't see the reason for that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/sector1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/agenda_izq"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Agenda" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/fondo"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/actividades_izq"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Actividades" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/suscribete_izq"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:text="Recibir Información de Juventud" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/sector3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I would like that all three images start from the left border, without any margin.

Thank you.

Comment: there must be whitespace in your images.

Comment: make sure ,your image does not contain white space background as per @MurtazaHussain said and one another thing is that use linearlayout with weight property as per your need,here seems your calculation related weight is not ok ,set their weight properly .it solves your issue 100% .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second image is linked to the left with no margin because that line:

```
android:background="@color/fondo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having Buttons with `drawableLeft` you might want to give using `LinearLayout`s as Buttons a try for increased flexibility of choosing how your images and text are displayed, like so:

```
 <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/button2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:minHeight="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewForButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/actividades_izg" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/fondo"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Actividades" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

You would then have one of the above `LinearLayouts` containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView` per "Button". To reference it, e.g. in `onCreateView`, you would then use:

```
 LinearLayout button1 = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Instead of a `LinearLayout` you might consider to use a `RelativeLayout` in order to align text *to the right* of the `ImageView`s as described in [Aligning a TextView and ImageView inside a LinearLayout, Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13112267/1791820)